# I exited out of terminal, re-opened, now every time I run rspec I get this error, what gives?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Seriously have no idea what has happened any help would be great thanks.

```
 GacntMac in ~/Desktop/rails_projects/sample_app on updating-users
    + bundle install                                              (Tue, Feb 05)
    Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
    Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
    Using rake (10.0.3) 
    Using i18n (0.6.1) 
    Using multi_json (1.5.0) 
    Using activesupport (3.2.11) 
    Using builder (3.0.4) 
    Using activemodel (3.2.11) 
    Using erubis (2.7.0) 
    Using journey (1.0.4) 
    Using rack (1.4.4) 
    Using rack-cache (1.2) 
    Using rack-test (0.6.2) 
    Using hike (1.2.1) 
    Using tilt (1.3.3) 
    Using sprockets (2.2.2) 
    Using actionpack (3.2.11) 
    Using mime-types (1.20.1) 
    Using polyglot (0.3.3) 
    Using treetop (1.4.12) 
    Using mail (2.4.4) 
    Using actionmailer (3.2.11) 
    Using arel (3.0.2) 
    Using tzinfo (0.3.35) 
    Using activerecord (3.2.11) 
    Using activeresource (3.2.11) 
    Installing bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1) with native extensions 
    Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
    mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/ruby.h


    Gem files will remain installed in /Users/GacntMac/.bundler/tmp/2663/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1 for inspection.
    Results logged to /Users/GacntMac/.bundler/tmp/2663/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1/ext/mri/gem_make.out
    An error occurred while installing bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
    Make sure that `gem install bcrypt-ruby -v '3.0.1'` succeeds before bundling.
    GacntMac in ~/Desktop/rails_projects/sample_app on updating-users
```

I cd'd to the directory the error says `ruby.h` should be in, but I don't see anything..

```
GacntMac in /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby
o ls -a                                                       (Tue, Feb 05)
.               ..              1.8             gems            site_ruby       user-gems       vendor_ruby
```

Edit: Added rvm info

```
GacntMac in /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby
o rvm info                                                    (Tue, Feb 05)
-bash: rvm: command not found
```

This is weird cause I've been playing with Rails for days, now it some how uninstalled its self?

This only started happening since I exited out of terminal and re-opened it. I'm lost and new to Rails so I have no idea what any of this means, just trying to follow a tutorial. Thanks!

Comment: Did you use RVM or rbenv at all to install Ruby? Which tutorial are you following?

Comment: @RyanBigg Michael Hartl's screencast, I'm right near the end, I just restarted my Terminal cause it froze for some reason, I used RVM.

Comment: Please add the output of `rvm info` to your question.

Comment: Some of your comments sound like you think that RVM is associated with Rails. It isn't, except for a distant connection via a Ruby that it manages. Rails and Ruby can exist and run correctly on a machine without RVM, RVM just makes it easier and somewhat safer to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to install software into the system installation of Ruby, put there by Apple.

RVM or rbenv will install things into a private sandbox in your home directory. The error shows the file isn't going there, so your RVM or rbenv isn't initialized correctly.

If you run RVM, execute `rvm info` from the command-line, and look at the information output, as a sanity check.

Comment: `GacntMac in /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby
o rvm info                                                    (Tue, Feb 05)
-bash: rvm: command not found` That's weird, I know for a fact I had it installed...

Comment: If you do it should be at `~/.rvm` for the recommended single-user installation.

Comment: Yeah it's there, and the folder is populated with a bunch of files, any idea what I should do?

Comment: After re-installing RVM, it is working again, I guess something must have messed up or something, it's working again now, thanks.